# Unable to replace escape character through String.replaceAll in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying a replace a `\` using `String.replaceAll` and i get an Exception while doing so.  Here is my code:

```
    String str = "1^\\";
    System.out.println("\nInitial string length: "+str.length()+ " Initial String is:     "+str);
    String temp = str.replaceAll("[&@;^\\]","");
```

This is the output:

```
Initial string length: 3 Initial String is: 1^\

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character     class near index 6
 [&@;^\]
  ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2254)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1818)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2190)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `\\` escaping is being swallowed by the string literal, so the string you're parsing as a regex is actually `[&@;^\]`.

`\]` in a regex escapes the `]`, so you have an unclosed character class.

You need to double-escape the `\`; once for the string literal and once for the regex.

Comment: Thank you SLaks...i did this modification String temp = str.replaceAll("[&@;^\\\\]",""); and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The escape character for String and regex are the same.  This means to get

```
\\\\ - in the String
\\ - in the regex
\ - means
```